# What is the point of gzip Reader.Close?

Tags: file, go, gzip

If I have a program like this, it fails as expected (on Windows):

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   old := "go1.16.5.src.tar.gz"
   os.Open(old)
   err := os.Rename(old, "new.tar.gz")
   // The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
   fmt.Println(err)
}
```

However this program succeeds:

```
package main

import (
   "compress/gzip"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   old := "go1.16.5.src.tar.gz"
   f, err := os.Open(old)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   gzip.NewReader(f)
   f.Close()
   os.Rename(old, "new.tar.gz")
}
```

even though I did not close the gzip reader. My question is: what is the point of closing the gzip reader? What "bad" can happen if you don't do it? I thought one possible reason was `http#Response.Body` [1], because if a response contains `Content-Encoding: gzip`, then Go will automatically wrap the Body in a `gzip.Reader`. If that was the case, then a Close method would be required, as Body being a `io.ReadCloser`, it must have a `Read` and `Close` method. However `gzip#Reader.Close` specifically says that it doesn't close the
underlying reader:

> Close closes the Reader. It does not close the underlying io.Reader.

So wrapping Body with gzip Reader directly would be bad, because the Body would be left open on Close. The source code confirms that they use a custom gzip type instead [2]. Interestingly, the Close method on this type [3] closes the underlying reader, but doesn't bother to close the gzip reader, even using `defer`. So I think it can be safe to omit using gzip Reader Close in the general case.

1. https://golang.org/pkg/net/http#Response.Body
2. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.16.5/src/net/http/transport.go#L2187
3. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.16.5/src/net/http/transport.go#L2831-L2833

Comment: Why/how does your first program fail?   I don't see why it would.  What error are you getting?

Comment: In windows, you cannot rename open files. The second one works because you closed the file before renaming it. The gzip reader has no function in the program, it deals with buffering and decompressing the underlying file. Since you closed the file, if you attempt to read from the gzip reader it will fail.

Comment: Oh, huh, I had no idea about that "rule" in Windows.   tyvm

Answer (score 10):

There is no reason to call `Close()` at this time, but that may change in the future.

The `Close()` method was originally used to tear down the background goroutine used by the deflater.  The background goroutine was removed in [a June, 2011 change list](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/07acc02a29ac74e7c0b08b4cd382bf71acd262).

The author of the CL wrote the following [in a comment on the CL](https://codereview.appspot.com/4548079#msg3):

> Close used to tear down the goroutine associated with
> the reader, but now there isn't one. Probably Close
> will go away entirely, but that's a separate CL.

They never got around to removing the `Close()` method before the [compatibility guarantee](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat) was introduced in the Go 1 release.

[As of June, 2020](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/0ebd5a8de05823109263bef31b38be8c29d2cd54/src/compress/flate/inflate.go#L354-L359) the method does not actually do anything. Any error encountered by the decompressor is returned from the `Close()` method.  The error is also returned from `Read()` when the application reads to to the end of the stream, so there's no need to call `Close()` to get the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of `Reader.Close`, it calls the underlying decompressor's `Close`, which ends up in [this method](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/golang/go/-/blob/src/compress/flate/inflate.go?L354):

```
func (f *decompressor) Close() error {
    if f.err == io.EOF {
        return nil
    }
    return f.err
}
```

So it seems like while it's not actually *doing* anything, it does relay an error from earlier operations on the stream. This aligns with the documentation of `Reader.Close`, which says:

> In order for the GZIP checksum to be verified, the reader must be
> fully consumed until the io.EOF.

So what "bad" can happen? Well, you can miss genuine errors if you haven't checked them before. It's important to check the error returned by `Close` (here and elsewhere when it's available) to make sure things are working as expected.

---

In your first code sample, you get an error because you're trying to rename an open file. Your second code sample closes the file before renaming it, so there's no error. Note that `gzip`'s `Close` does not close the underlying reader.

Comment: @StevenPenny: based on the documentation, I imagine this would happen when the checksum fails to verify.

Comment: @StevenPenny: right. Recall that it implements `io.ReadCloser`, so `Close` has to return an error. I think in this case, as you say, if you diligently check all errors on read ops, you'll catch it before the close. I'm a bit mystified how this relates to the rest of your question though (renaming files before closing them)

Comment: @StevenPenny: yes, based on the implementation shown above it's not needed, since it doesn't actually do anything, except relay the error.